# Continuously running a Spring Batch job using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have to write a batch Job that should read certain entries from a database table and process and write it to another table. Every time the job is done, I have to wait for 1  second and start reading and writing from and to the DB and this should go on. Please hell me to understand the following,

1. Is it OK to use Thread.sleep at the after job completion listener?
2. Am still trying to find out a way to start the job over. Please guide me to find a good approach.
3. I am using Java based configurations. Here how to specify the chunk(int) value for both reader and writer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example that should show you the answer to all three questions: https://github.com/joechev/examples/tree/master/fixed-delay-batch

1. What are you using Thread.sleep for?  The fixed delay?  See the `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled` annotations in the example.
2. See (1)
3. See the CHUNK_SIZE value in the job config in the example.

Comment: Thanks. It helped :)